# Pulling item properties from Microsoft Sharepoint document library with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm able to successfully pull file metadata from my SharePoint library with the Microsoft Graph API, but am having trouble pulling the properties of an item:

[image: Sharepoint item properties]

I can get a partial list of properties using this endpoint:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{}/items/{}/children?$expand=listItem($expand=fields)

But the list that comes from this endpoint doesn't match the list of properties that exists on the item.

For example, below is a list of fields that come from that endpoint - you can see that '.Push Too Salsify.' (one of the fields I need) is not present. There are also other fields that exist but don't appear in the item properties:

{'ParentLeafNameLookupId': '466', 'CLIPPING_x0020_STATUS': 'Not Started', 'Edit': '0', 'EditorLookupId': '67', '_ComplianceTagWrittenTime': '', 'RequiredField': 'teams/WORKFLOWDEMO/Shared Documents/1062CQP6.Phase4/1062CQP-Phase4-Size.tif', 'PM_x0020_SIGN_x0020_OFF': 'No', 'QA_x0020_APPROVED': 'No', 'ImageWidth': 3648, 'PM_x0020_Approval_x0020_Status': '-', 'AuthorLookupId': '6', 'SelectedFlag': '0', 'NameOrTitle': '1062CQP-Phase4-Size.tif', 'ItemChildCount': '0', 'FolderChildCount': '0', 'LinkFilename': '1062CQP-Phase4-Size.tif', 'ParentVersionStringLookupId': '466', 'PHOTOSTATUS': 'Not Started', '@odata.etag': '"c4b7516e-64df-46d2-b916-a1ee6f29d24a,8"', 'Thumbnail': '3648', '_x002e_Approval_x0020_Status_x002e_': 'Approved', 'Date_x0020_Created': '2019-10-09T04:25:40Z', '_CommentCount': '', 'Created': '2019-10-09T04:25:33Z', 'PreviewOnForm': '0', '_ComplianceTag': '', 'FileLeafRef': '1062CQP-Phase4-Size.tif', 'ImageHeight': 3648, 'LinkFilenameNoMenu': '1062CQP-Phase4-Size.tif', '_ComplianceFlags': '', 'ContentType': 'Document', 'Preview': '3648', 'ImageSize': '3648', 'Product_x0020_Category': 'Baseball', 'DATE_x0020_ASSIGNED': '2019-10-09T04:25:40Z', 'DateCreated': '2019-10-09T04:25:40Z', 'WORKFLOW_x0020_SELECTION': ['Select'], 'Predecessors': [], 'FileType': 'tif', 'LEGAL_x0020_APPROVED': 'No', 'PUSH_x0020_READY': False, 'FileSizeDisplay': '74966432', 'id': '466', '_LikeCount': '', '_ComplianceTagUserId': '', 'Modified': '2019-10-09T14:41:25Z', 'DocIcon': 'tif', '_UIVersionString': '0.7', '_CheckinComment': ''}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've scoured the documentation and can't seem to find the correct endpoint to pull item properties from a Sharepoint DriveItem.

Comment: Do you get all the columns (fields) if you use the "lists" segment instead of "drives"?

Comment: @PaulSchaeflein Thanks for your response. I tried pulling each list - and none of the lists associated with the specific site correspond to the full set of fields found on the properties of my items.

Comment: @PaulSchaeflein Correction - i found the designated list, but same issue. It's missing about 12 to 15 column fields that are tied to the list.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?  What are the column types of the columns that are missing?  Are any of the missing columns calculated columns or something along those lines?